# sound volume settings doesn't do anything

Tags: sound, 16.04, vlc

I installed Ubuntu the other day, and I am quite new to it. I've noticed that the sound volume setting at the top right hand side of the screen doesn't affect the volume of my media players (it may affect system sounds but i haven't really noticed any difference either).

I turn it all the way up it doesn't affect the sound, all the way down to mute and the same thing.

Is this normal? Should that volume setting affect only system sounds or should it also affect the sounds from media players? If so how do I remedy this problem?

I'm using a combination of VLC media player and the Google chrome Plex App.
Running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

This could help, once my friend had this issue and following these steps fixed it:

1. Removed `~/.config/pulse` directory.
2. Started Pulse Audio.

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
   pulseaudio --start
   ```

Incase if its still showing errors you will have to reinstall pulse audio and equalizer.

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio pulseaudio-equalizer
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
pulseaudio --start
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: Volume control in Ubuntu works for most everyone so recommending PulseAudio volume control as an alternative doesn't solve the problem. First you should find out what type of hardware is involved and checking if there are bug reports on it or other users of the same hardware have the same problem. The other answer of resinstalling PulseAudio is a good one that might work but the OP never responded.