# Sound not controlled by system volume anymore in 20.04

Tags: sound

Since I upgraded to 20.04 the system sound control doesn't seem to affect applications anymore. I press volume up and down, I get the little volume popup on screen, and the system wide volume in ubuntu adjusts accordingly. But that doesn't seem to affect VLC or Firefox at all.

I tried removing the pulse config directory like in https://askubuntu.com/a/772115/284658, but when I tried to remove pulseaudio and pulseaudio-equalizer it wanted to remove ubuntu-desktop which didn't seem...good. And the first part didn't help.

Standard ubuntu20.04, based on minimal installation with installed third party drivers.during installation. Latest updates. I'm not 100% sure which audio system or drivers or things I'm using, but everything was working fine in 19.10 and it's the same problem on both my desktop and laptop.

Comment: install pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control)  : sudo apt install pavucontrol , use its playing/recording tab

Comment: I don't want to control volume per application, just want all applications to follow the system volume. Even if I lower system volume to 0 firefox with youtube keeps going at its own volume. I tried pavucontrol and it doesn't seem to help.